# Column names as value in every row

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I've got a DataFrame that looks like the following (first 3 rows)

```
  cap_color gill_color spore_print_color stalk_color veil_color
1     brown      black             black      purple      white
2    yellow      black             brown      purple      white
3     white      brown             brown      purple      white
```

Now I'd like to get it to show up as such:

```
 color              part
1   brown         cap_color
2  yellow         cap_color
3   white         cap_color
4   black        gill_color
5   black        gill_color
6   brown        gill_color
7   black spore_print_color
8   brown spore_print_color
9   brown spore_print_color
10 purple       stalk_color
11 purple       stalk_color
12 purple       stalk_color
13  white        veil_color
14  white        veil_color
15  white        veil_color
```

I know the issue can be solved via looping but I was wondering whether a vectorized function exists to make this faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks more complicated than it is, just use `tidyr`, `gather()`

The code is simple:

```
require(tidyr)
newDF <- df%>%
gather(part, color)
```

You should have what you are looking for....

Comment: That was indeed way easier than I imagined it to be. Thank you very much.

Comment: All the old fashioned ways...AWFUL! This is FANTASTIC STUFF. If you get a chance spend some time in tidyr and dplyr tutorials...they make life SO EASY!

Comment: I've been working with tidyr and dplyr for a while now but I couldn't seem to find the right function for this task. Might have not been working with the libraries for long enough. Thank you though :)